# File Download via Spring does not work in Firefox

Tags: java, spring, jsp, firefox

I have written a program to upload and download files (.doc, .xls and .txt) from DB (mySQL). It is written using Spring MVC. The upload and download is working correctly in IE however in Firefox it is not working as excepted.

To download the file a link is provided in the JSP on click of which the "File Download" dialog box will pop-up. In IE this dialog box pops up and allows to open and/or save the file in the correct format (i.e. .doc, .xls and/or .txt).

In Firefox it is doing the following on click on the link :

1. For .doc files, it opens the files (no File Download pop-up)
2. For .xls files, the File Download pop-up is seen however the file extension is not taken as .xls instead taking it as file.do

### FileController Class

```
public class FileController extends AbstractFormController{
SearchResultService searchResultService;

public void setSearchResultService(SearchResultService searchResultService){
this.searchResultService = searchResultService;
}


@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
ResultSet result = searchResultService.getAttachment(Integer.parseInt(arg0.getParameter("prbId")));
byte[] buff = new byte[100000];
try {
result.next();
if(!(result.getBinaryStream(1)==null)){
String filename = "fname."+result.getString("file_ext");
if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("txt")){
InputStream is = result.getBinaryStream(1);
OutputStream out = arg1.getOutputStream();
arg1.reset();
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buff)) != -1) {
out.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
}
arg1.setContentType("");
arg1.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename);
is.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
}else{
arg1.reset();
if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("doc")||result.getString("file_ext").equals("docx")){
arg1.setContentType("application/msword");
}else if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("xls")||result.getString("file_ext").equals("xlsx")){
arg1.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
}else if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("pdf")){
arg1.setContentType("application/pdf");
}
arg1.setHeader("Content-Desposition","attachment; filename="+filename);
byte[] bytesGot = result.getBytes(1);
ServletOutputStream outs = arg1.getOutputStream();
outs.write(bytesGot);
outs.flush();
outs.close();
}
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return new ModelAndView();
}
}
```

### JSP that calls FileController class

```
<a href="<%=contextPath%>/file.do?prbId=<%=desc.getProblemId() %>">Download File</a>
```

All the extensions are saved/retrieved in the db correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For point 2 - You have a spelling mistake in setting the header.

```
arg1.setHeader("Content-Desposition","attachment; filename="+filename);
```

It should be Content-Disposition not Content-Desposition.

For point 1 - try resetting your browser preferences. See [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions) link for more information.

Comment: Thank you Manish, it was because of the mistake the program was not working as expected. However all the files are by default being downloaded in local i.e. on click of open button in the file download pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper headers. I am setting these headers to download my .xls file and its working.

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Content-type", "application-download");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class FileController extends AbstractFormController{
    SearchResultService searchResultService;

    public void setSearchResultService(SearchResultService searchResultService){
    this.searchResultService = searchResultService;
    }


    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    ResultSet result = searchResultService.getAttachment(Integer.parseInt(arg0.getParameter("prbId")));
    byte[] buff = new byte[100000];
    try {
    result.next();
    if(!(result.getBinaryStream(1)==null)){
    String filename = "fname."+result.getString("file_ext");
    if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("txt")){
    InputStream is = result.getBinaryStream(1);
    OutputStream out = arg1.getOutputStream();
    arg1.reset();
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buff)) != -1) {
    out.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    arg1.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename);
    is.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    }else{
    arg1.reset();
    if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("doc")||result.getString("file_ext").equals("docx")){
    arg1.setContentType("application/msword");
    }else if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("xls")||result.getString("file_ext").equals("xlsx")){
    arg1.setContentType("application/msexcel");
    }else if(result.getString("file_ext").equals("pdf")){
    arg1.setContentType("application/pdf");
    }
    arg1.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+filename);
    byte[] bytesGot = result.getBytes(1);
    ServletOutputStream outs = arg1.getOutputStream();
    outs.write(bytesGot);
    outs.flush();
    outs.close();
    }
    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ModelAndView();
    }
    }
```